# Closing questions as off topic if they have an answer on mathoverflow?

Tags: discussion, mathoverflow, unanswered-questions

I think that questions on mathoverflow are in most cases on topic here. Does it make sense to have the question on both sites, with a complete answer on mathoverflow and here it appears as unanswered?

A similar question was raised [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/310/15416) a few years ago. I think the subject has changed a little since then as now MO is part of the SE network.

What do you think? I think closing as off topic (although not totally true) is the easiest way to get the question from the [unanswered queue](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141/the-crusade-of-answers). Of course another possibility would be to copy the MO answer here with a reference. This is the way some of us have done it before to mark the question as unanswered.

Comment: I think it depends on the question. I'm not sure that "off topic" is correct. In either case, this may give me the incentive I need to figure out what sort of answer I was looking for on some of my cross-posts.

Comment: @AsafKaragila For a particular example, see e.g. [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/179941/15416)

Comment: MO's and MSE's audiences are very different. Something that might be regarded as a good answer on MO, might not be so on MSE. This is of particular importance if we remember that answers are not for the OP only.

Comment: @GitGud Good point, although one could argue about the "very", there is quite some overlap.

Comment: I would much rather leave a question unanswered than make the ridiculous assertion that a question answered on MO is off-topic. Asaf has the right idea.

Comment: @Brian: That last sentence is axiomatically true... ;-)

Comment: @Asaf: But I'm not sure I'm comfortable taking that as an axiom.

Comment: @Cameron: If you like, I could force this over you... :-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I feel that the best path is to mimic comment answers:

Notify, if possible, to the MO answerer about the MSE copy; or post a CW answer with a link to the MO answer and a short notice saying that the answer was given (and accepted, if applicable) on mathoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Since MO is part of the SE2.0 network now, a mod could migrate the question to MO and a MO mod could then dupe-close (or merge, if adequate) it there.