# Exact duplicates of questions posted on MO

Tags: discussion, support, exact-duplicates, mathoverflow

I wonder why we can't declare a question posted on MSE (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497256/when-is-a-field-a-nontrivial-field-of-fractions)) an exact duplicate of a question posted on MO (like [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47103/is-every-field-the-field-of-fractions-of-an-integral-domain)) and viceversa? (I'd find it useful if we could do this.)

Comment: There were some older discussions, however, some things might have changed, since that was before MO joined SE network: [Vote to Close as Exact Duplicate should Accept MathOverflow Question URLs](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/310/vote-to-close-as-exact-duplicate-should-accept-mathoverflow-question-urls); [What to do with questions that are exact duplicates from MathOverflow?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/what-to-do-with-questions-that-are-exact-duplicates-from-mathoverflow).

Comment: On some occasions there are perfectly valid reason why the same question could be asked on both sites. (The answers on MO tend to be much more sophisticated.) This was pointed out by several user in this (rather heated) discussion: [What, when and will we migrate questions to MO 2.0?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0) This post is also related: [Cross posting, or flag for migration?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10265/cross-posting-or-flag-for-migration)

Comment: My question was based on the fact that now MO joined to SE and such a feature can't be so hard to be implemented.

Comment: You could always choose to close as off-topic, filling in as the reason, duplicate of Question xxxxx on MO. Of course, that's that what "off-topic" is intended for, but maybe that wouldn't bother some people. But have a look at the discussions Martin dug up, before you go down that path.

Comment: I am aware that I have already posted many links here, but the discussion of the same issue on meta.MO seems definitely relevant: [Allow questions to be closed as duplicates of questions on math.stackexchange.com](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/543/allow-questions-to-be-closed-as-duplicates-of-questions-on-math-stackexchange-co)

Answer (score 16):

My opinion is that questions should only be marked as duplicate only if they are on the same site. For example, if the same question is asked on the site for professional linguists and on the site for English language learners, it requires different answers and different level of detail. Perhaps the difference between MO and MSE is not that big, but there still is a difference. See also this discussion on meta.SO: [duplicate questions on other SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/duplicate-questions-on-other-se-sites)

If the two questions, which seem duplicate, are posted at the same time, the best option seems to be migrating one of them and closing as a duplicate. Such opinion was also expressed in a discussion on meta.MO: [Close cross posts between here and MSE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/423/close-cross-posts-between-here-and-mse). If neither of the posts has answers and it cannot be closed as a duplicate, flagging for moderation attention has been suggested as the solution [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11023/i-lied-about-a-closing-reason/11024#11024).

If it is not cross-post, but simply two identical questions, then posting a CW-answer with a link to MathOverflow and some brief explanation seems like a good solution to me. This was suggested here: [Closing questions as off topic if they have an answer on mathoverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10072/closing-questions-as-off-topic-if-they-have-an-answer-on-mathoverflow) Since this suggestion received 16 upvotes, it seems as a community consensus. (Although this was discussed before MO joined SE network.)

Comment: Regarding your final paragraph, MO migrated on Jun 24, 2013. One day before the question was asked. In fact, the question states that "now that MO is so nearby ..." somewhere inside.

Comment: I think cross posting (with a link to the original) to another site when once has not received the answer in one site, gives better exposure to the problem as usually the active user groups in the two sites MO and MSE are different. And I don't see how cross posting in such a situation can damage the social objective of either of the sites of SE in general. Thanks.

Comment: @MLT Well, several people have said that they do not like posting a question on two sites *at the same time*. If you have  a look at questions tagged ([meta-tag:cross-posting]), you will certainly find several answers saying this. Personally, I do not have a problem having question on both sites, if the links to the other question are given in both places and if there is a sufficient time gap between them. When they are posted almost simultaneously is the situation, which seems questionable to me. (And, as it seems, to several other users of this site.)