# How should we handle cross-site duplicates?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closing, exact-duplicates, unanswered-questions

There are some questions which are answered quite well by a nearly-identical question on another site (say, computer science's stack exchange, or math overflow). Should those questions get answers just pointing towards those other sites? Should those questions be closed? etc.

Comment: Related: [Closing questions as off topic if they have an answer on mathoverflow?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10072/). My personal preference is to write a more accessible version of the answer from the other site. For example, I tried this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/612602/), which made sense because the MO answer was too terse for the OP to digest. (Though it's not clear if the OP benefited: he did not revisit MSE after my answer.)

Comment: Related: [Questions x-posted and answered on MO](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2371)

Comment: Both of those questions seem basically related to my question, but have about three different answers among them...

Comment: For the ones that should be closed, the software will sometimes not allow for closing as an off-site duplicate. In these cases, it is necessary to use the custom close reason, which is available under Close -> Off Topic -> Other, and leave a message explaining the reason for voting to close. This is the general method for voting to close when the software does not  have a specific reason for the situation at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Post No Bulls](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/111742/post-no-bulls) answered this in a Comment, and I'm promoting it to an Answer of the Community Wiki persuasion:

> Related: [Closing questions as off topic if they have an answer on mathoverflow?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10072/). My personal preference is to write a more accessible version of the answer from the other site. For example, I tried this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/612602/), which made sense because the MO answer was too terse for the OP to digest. (Though it's not clear if the OP benefited: he did not revisit MSE after my answer.)